# Error: Unable to instantiate module 'Launch': System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

When I try to upload ios application from Unreal Engine to iTunes Connect I get the following error:

ERROR: Unable to instantiate module 'Launch': System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Everything it feels like.

Log:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): Running: mono "/Applications/UE_4.23/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe" anwenoprojo IOS Development -Project="/Users/williamapelgren/Desktop/anwenoprojo 4.23/anwenoprojo.uproject"  "/Users/williamapelgren/Desktop/anwenoprojo 4.23/anwenoprojo.uproject" -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="/Users/williamapelgren/Desktop/anwenoprojo 4.23" -skipdeploy -distribution -flushmac -Manifest="/Users/williamapelgren/Desktop/anwenoprojo 4.23/Intermediate/Build/Manifest.xml" -NoHotReload -log="/Users/williamapelgren/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UBT-anwenoprojo-IOS-Development_2.txt"
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):   ERROR: Unable to instantiate module 'Launch': System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):            at System.Number.ParseSingle (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) [0x00083] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):            at System.Single.Parse (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00000] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):            at System.Single.Parse (System.String s) [0x0000b] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):            at UnrealBuildTool.ReadOnlyIOSTargetRules.get_RuntimeVersion () [0x00010] in <ce5e2d2c06a1499db483036381a9dbb3>:0
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):            at Launch..ctor (UnrealBuildTool.ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) [0x006e6] in <f6600978a9e84d1fa5020f1c3dc25dc3>:0
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):            at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):            at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):          (referenced via anwenoprojo.Target.cs)
PackagingResults: Error: Unable to instantiate module 'Launch': System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): Took 12,137415s to run mono, ExitCode=5
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (/Users/williamapelgren/Library/Logs/Unreal Engine/LocalBuildLogs/UBT-anwenoprojo-IOS-Development_2.txt)
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=5 (5)
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS): RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
PackagingResults: Error: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
```

It should upload properly​!

Answer (score 0):

Lets try got find get_RuntimeVersion that is called according to this line

```
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):            at UnrealBuildTool.ReadOnlyIOSTargetRules.get_RuntimeVersion () [0x00010] in <ce5e2d2c06a1499db483036381a9dbb3>:0
```

we will find UEBuildIOS.cs and ReadOnlyIOSTargetRules partial class. There is the property "RuntimeVersion". This property is evaluated by parsing runtime version (iOS version specifically). Version is a float value like 11.0 or 12.0.

Lets have a look at this line

```
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):   ERROR: Unable to instantiate module 'Launch': System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
UATHelper: Packaging (iOS):            at System.Number.ParseSingle (System.String value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) [0x00083] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0
```

Input string was not in a correct format - I think the problem is decimal separator. I tried to change my Mac setting to use different separator but it doesn't work.

Then I tried to use "." right before getter in UEBuildIOS.cs

```
        public float RuntimeVersion
        {
            get {
             System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
             customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

             System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
             return float.Parse(Inner.ProjectSettings.RuntimeVersion); 
            }
        }
```

And now app builds and deploys to iPhone.

It just a workaround, we need to go deeper to understand a reason.